# Prepend tail -f output with filename

Tags: linux, bash, logging, monitoring, tail

To monitor a system I need to constantly have a log tail running (it greps out some data as well). It's basically

```
tail -f *.log' | egrep -v '(str1|str2)
```

The output of tail is very noisy and it constantly prints the file that it is currently tailing from.

```
==> example1.log <==
log example 1
==> example2.log <==
log example 2
```

I would like to be able to change the output I'm getting from tail -f *.log and prefix the output with the filename on a per line basis so that the output looks like this:

```
example1.log:log example 1
example2.log:log example 2
```

I'm looking for a simple hack to achieve this as it's simply for my monitoring of log files in real time using tail -f. It might be possible to even replace the output using sed to take away the newlines and other data and prefix.

Anyone have a clue? Would be greatly appreciated for this monitoring hack.

Thanks! JC

I've tried replacing the output using sed but it's not logical.

Because I'm grepping data out, the output of tail is constantly repeating lines such as

```
==> example1.log <==
some data
==> example2.log <==
==> example1.log <==
==> example2.log <==
some data
==> example1.log <==
```

It's quickly become a kind of difficult task and I really just need the filename prepended to the output as it were with grep.

I need to monitor the realtime logs and I haven't found multitail or other commands to meet the needs, if someone has a working example I'd be forever grateful.

Comment: If your `tail` supporst the `-q` option/flag then use it maybe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195922/show-filename-at-begining-of-each-line-when-tailing-multiple-files-at-once

Comment: It doesn't per my remarks on multitail. It seems like a lot of all around bad answers on the post or people perhaps not listening to the poster.

Comment: Not being able to reply to the comments inline in strange. Am I missing something? The logs are apache logs. I'll just use 'tail -q' and add what I need to the LogFormat in apache to achieve the desired results, but honestly, I'd like an answer. I should probably just hack the tail source code myself for this.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have too many files, you could probably just spawn a separate pipeline for each. eg:

```
for i in *; do tail -f "$i" | sed "s@^@$i: @" & done; wait
```

That omits the filter, so maybe:

```
for i in *; do tail -f "$i" | sed -e '/str1/d' -e '/str2/d' -e "s@^@$i: @" & done; wait
```

This runs a `tail -f` pipeline in the background for each file, piping the output to a `sed` instance which prepends each line with the file name.  You'll want to clean up the processes afterwords.  If this is in a script, record the pids and forward any signals to them, otherwise, just clean up with `pkill` when you're done.

You can also just do:

```
tail -f *.log | awk '/^==>[^<]*<==$/ {fname = $2; next } ! /str1/ && ! /str2/ {printf "%s: %s\n", fname, $0}'
```

which seems a bit cleaner and has fewer issues with potentially interleaved output, but I would worry a bit more about buffering issues and the match on the filename is a bit fragile.